# Android actionbar autohide

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Is there an easy way to autohide the Actionbar?  Similar to the way that the url bar in the Google Chrome app disappears when the user scrolls down, but then reappears when the user scrolls back up.

Comment: Post your code, what have your tried ?

Answer (score 1):

It's name "Quick Return Pattern" You can find some useful libraries for this ux pattern from here:
https://android-arsenal.com/tag/136

And you can find more details about this pattern from here:
https://plus.google.com/+RomanNurik/posts/1Sb549FvpJt

I can post an example of qucik return pattern for a Listview with a quick return header. You can change it for ScrollView

```
yourListView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
         @SuppressLint("NewApi")
         @Override
         public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            int scrollOffset = 0;
            float transitionY;

            if (firstVisibleItem > 0) {
               scrollOffset += headerHeight;
               if (firstVisibleItem > 1) {
                  scrollOffset += (firstVisibleItem - 1) * cellHeight;
               }
            }

            if (yourListView.getChildCount() > 0) {
               scrollOffset += -yourListView.getChildAt(0).getTop();
               scrollOffset = -scrollOffset;
            }

            float scrollDelta = scrollOffset - prevOffset;
            float nextY = mQuickReturnView.getY() + scrollDelta;

            if (nextY < minRawY) {
               transitionY = minRawY;
            }
            else if (nextY > qReturnDelta) {
               transitionY = qReturnDelta;
            }
            else {
               transitionY = nextY;
            }

            mQuickReturnView.setY(transitionY);
            prevOffset = scrollOffset;
         }

         @Override
         public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
         }
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the hide() method like:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.hide();
```

But its API version dependent, check here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html